# Deriving a thousands or hundreds range from a number in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have several thousand job numbers stored in a SQL Server database, and I'd like to be able to derive what 1000's or 100's range they fall into for purposes of grouping in a third party application, which is integrated with our jobs list.

How can I extract the 1000's group that each job number would belong to in a column in my query's result set?

Examples:
I would like for my output to be:

```
JOB_NUMBER      JOB_GROUP
678             0-999
679             0-999
1517            1000-1999
2011            2000-2999
2150            2000-2999
...etc.
```

Comment: can you show the original table structure here?

Comment: select cast(cast(JOB_NUMBER / 1000 as int) * 1000 as  varchar) + ' - ' + cast((cast(JOB_NUMBER / 1000 as int)  + 1) * 1000  - 1 as  varchar)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If job_number is an integer, you can use this:

```
select job_number, 
       convert(varchar(10), job_number / 1000 * 1000) 
     + '-' 
     + convert(varchar(10), job_number / 1000 * 1000 + 999) Range
  from whatever
```

Comment: Did not work for me on Postgres DB event after syntax changes...something like this worked instead, posting it just for others use. Thanks! 
select job_number,
cast(job_number /1000-0.5 as int)*1000 || '-' || cast(job_number /1000-0.5 as int)*1000 +999 from whatever

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression:

```
SELECT 
JOB_NUMBER,
JOB_GROUP = CASE 
      WHEN JOB_NUMBER < 1000 THEN '0-999'
      WHEN JOB_NUMBER < 2000 THEN '1000-1999'
      WHEN JOB_NUMBER < 3000 THEN '2000-2999'
    END
```

Comment: I'd like something a little less hard-coded, as the job numbers will be continually increasing, and I don't want to have to add a new WHEN clause every time the job numbers roll into another block of 1000

Comment: Correct, LittleBobby.  Sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT JOB_NUMBER/1000 AS JOB_NUMBER,MIN(JOB_NUMBER) AS MIN_NUMBER,
           MAX(JOB_NUMBER) AS MAX_NUMBER
    FROM <TABLE>
    GROUP BY NUMBER/1000)
SELECT M.JOB_NUMBER,
       CAST(MIN_NUMBER AS VARCHAR(20))+'-'+CAST(MAX_NUMBER AS VARCHAR(20))
FROM  <TABLE> M 
JOIN  CTE 
ON    MIN_NUMBER<= M.JOB_NUMBER
AND   MAX_NUMBER >=M.JOB_NUMBER
ORDER BY M.JOB_NUMBER
```